# How I can use the data of Excel of the first column in datetime?

Tags: python, excel, datetime, timestamp, xlrd

The version of python is python 3.8, I have this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import xlrd


archivo = 'LB2018.xlsx'

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(archivo)

dias = []

hoja = wb.sheet_by_name('LB2018')

for i in range(hoja.nrows):
    dtt = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(hoja.row(i)[0].value, wb.datemode)
    timestamp = dt.datetime.timestamp(dtt)
    dias.append(timestamp)

print(dias)
```

The error said:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

and I need to have timestamp to use this code for the next equations.

Comment: show the full error

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Check your Excel sheet, you most likely have a value in column 0 which is not a valid date format. I created an Excel Sheet, populated dates in column 0 and it runs without any issues using `xlrd` 1.2.0.

Comment: Also, it should be mentioned, that newer version of `xlrd` do not read `xlsx` files anymore! Version 1.2.0 was the last one doing so. See also: https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest

Comment: File "<ipython-input-8-bb29416d4813>", line 46, in <module>
    dtt = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(hoja.row(i)[0].value, wb.datemode)

  File "C:\Users\Manuel Ramirez\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xldate.py", line 144, in xldate_as_datetime
    if xldate < 60:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: that's the full eerror